# Escaping semicolon in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-real-escape-string

In PHPMyAdmin I want to replace "aa;bb" -> "aabb", by running the query:

```
UPDATE `question` SET `text` = REPLACE(`text`, 'aa;bb', 'aabb') WHERE INSTR(`text`, 'aa;bb') > 0;
```

but I get an error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''aa)' at line 1

The error occurs always I put a semicolon in the string.
Also, the semicolon does not work in searh or find and replace in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I've found working answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817066/4187751

Comment: @JeSa Finally a working solution. Thank you! 

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the delimiter from a semicolon to something else, I used a vertical bar.

Comment: This is not an answer.. You can put it under comment.

Comment: How is it not an answer? The problem is that the semicolon is being treated as a delimiter. There doesn't seem to be a way to escape the delimiter, so you need to change it to something else.

Comment: This answer solved my problem, so to me it's an answer. It tells me exactly what to do to get what I want in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

> The error occurs always I put a semicolon in the string. Also, the
>   semicolon does not work in searh or find and replace in PHPMyAdmin

Try this:

```
UPDATE `question` SET `text` = REPLACE(`text`, 'aa\;bb', 'aabb') WHERE INSTR(`text`, 'aa;bb') > 0;
```