# Update replace semicolon in SQL gets syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sql-update

I import an SQL file to my database but there is something wrong. All punctuation at the end of a sentence/phrase have extra space.

**Example:**

```
This is a sentence .
This , as you can see , is a problem .
Do it !
```

**Should be:**

```
This is a sentence.
This, as you can see, is a problem.
Do it!
```

To correct, I am planning to run SQL commands on phpMyAdmin in this context

```
UPDATE book SET content = REPLACE(content,' .','.');
UPDATE book SET content = REPLACE(content,' ,',',');
UPDATE book SET content = REPLACE(content,' ?','?');
UPDATE book SET content = REPLACE(content,' !','!');
UPDATE book SET content = REPLACE(content,' :',':');
```

So far so good. But When I tried it on a semicolon like this

```
UPDATE book SET content = REPLACE(content,' ;',';');
```

I get syntax error #1064 when I simulate the query.

I tried escaping it with a backslash like this but same error

```
UPDATE book SET content = REPLACE(content,' \;','\;');
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL server are you targeting? This works just fine in MSSQL v13

Comment: Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
    Server type: Percona Server
    Server version: 5.6.40-84.0-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.0, Revision 47234b3
    Protocol version: 10
    User: 
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Siteground shared host confirm that they are using version 5.6. They said this version is better than 13. I need to prepare leave my host

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
delimiter /
UPDATE book SET content = REPLACE(content,' ;',';');
delimiter ;
```

**EDIT:**

It was a field in phpMyAdmin which is set to semicolon by default. Set on /.

[image]

Comment: I am 99% sure that this is the case. Try a different delimiter except ' / ', like ' //// '
After changed delete semicolon in the end :)


```UPDATE book SET content = REPLACE(content, ' ;', ';')```